# cPanel email not working

Tags: dns, email, cpanel, nameserver, cname

I have a domain registered with Dynadot, and hosting on GoDaddy. I'm using cloudflare as a CDN and I've added CNAME records for 'mail' and 'email' but emails aren't coming through to the addresses on that domain (set up through cpanel). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: I can send emails and that seems to work fine

Comment: CNAME records for `mail` and `email` don't have any bearing on email coming through.  What have you set for your `MX` records?

Comment: I've set an MX record for mail.mydomain.com, but still nothing's coming through

Comment: Nevermind, I've got it working now, adding a txt record to include the mail server address seemed to do the trick :)